# Is it possible to pin a badge to my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, badges, network-profile

Is there a way to 'pin/showcase' a badge on Stack Overflow onto my profile? I don't see a way to do it, I also checked the badges tab but still don't see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no officially supported way of showcasing a specific badge on your profile.

You could, however, take a screenshot of it and upload it to the "About" section.